# spark magic - enter sql context as string

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Connecting to spark over livy works fine in Jupyter,
as does the following spark magic:

```
%%spark -c sql
select * from some_table
```

Now how can I use string variables to query tables?
The following does not work:

```
query = 'select * from some_table'
```

Next cell:

```
%%spark -c sql
query
```

Nor does the following work:

```
%%spark -c sql
'select * from some_table'
```

Any ideas? Is it possible to "echo" the content of a string variable into a cell?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like I found a solution.
There is a function that turns strings into cell magic commands:

```
%%local

from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()

line = '-c sql -o df'
query = 'select * from some_table'
ipython.run_cell_magic(magic_name='spark', line=line, cell=query)
```

After this, the query is in the pandas dataframe df.